# Launch Coroutine in class without Destructor/Lifecycle

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am currently learning how to use Coroutines and under Android it is pretty clear to me. When i want to use a coroutine in a `Fragment` for example I just implement `CoroutineScope` and cancel that scope in `onDestroy`. But how do I go about this in a class that is not a Singleton/global and where I don't have a 100% safe way to cancel all running coroutines because there is no destructor, onDestroy, etc. that is called everytime (the Android `Application` class for example). Do I just implement `CoroutineScope` without calling `cancel` or do I use `runBlocking` maybe? Would that lead to memory leaks?

Answer (score 3):

You can use GlobalScope. 
https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/index.html

That being said - you probably shouldn't. You `should` have control over your running jobs. Perhaps you can create suspend functions inside your non-lifecycle class and have them called from somewhere, where you have control over lifecycle(be it Activity, Fragment, Presenter, ViewModel).

Not having this control might lead to both memory and work leaks.

Hope this helps. Cheers!

EDIT:

One thing I didn't think of at the time was a delegate:

```
class YourNonLifecycleThingy(
    private val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope
) : CoroutineScope by coroutineScope
```

where coroutineScope is e.g. your activity's coroutineScope.